Is this the right code to run a QSVC algorithm on a dataset?
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=X_train.shape[1], reps=2, entanglement='linear')
sampler = Sampler()
fidelity = ComputeUncompute(sampler=sampler)
kernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(fidelity = fidelity, feature_map=feature_map)
qsvc = QSVC(quantum_kernel=kernel)
qsvc.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = qsvc.predict(X_test)

With this code, I am trying to predict results on a dataset using this code and QSVC. The code crashes at qsvc.fit(). I let the program run for an hour, and it was not doing anything. Additionally, I do not know if the code I have written is right, in terms of being able to work. Can anyone help me with this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you provide the exact error you're encountering?

It is getting stuck at qsvc.fit(). I let it run for around an hour and the code was still not doing anything.
